# Admob is showing test ads even though the app is ready

Tags: android, admob, ads, google-mobile-ads, firebase-admob

I have a problem that the ads are still beta ads even though the app is in Google Play and I registered it in Admob and the Admob page shows me that it is ready.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There are no more details than this

Answer (score 0):

If you have added your device id as a test device id either while making the ad request or on the Google AdMob console then they will treat you as a test User even though the app you are using is uploaded to playstore.

Try removing `.addTestDevice("")` from the code and check the AdMob console and remove the device id from there as well.

Post that you should start seeing real ads. Allow it some time as it won't be spontaneous.

Comment: No, it is not a test device and it shows a test ad

Comment: No device added as test device

Answer (score 0):

This is my experience:

there are three places where you need to update the ad id
Which is in `activity`, `viewMain`, `AndroidManifest` files, after updating in these files, should be good.